# CakePHP is not working in WAMP server

Tags: cakephp-1.3, wamp

when I install cakephp in wamp it give some deprecated error, not include pages from its 'pages' folder, not get it css from webroot/css folder but when total project paste in XAMP server it works properly.
Please give some suggestion.

Comment: It would be helpful if you copy/pasted the errors you are receiving.

Comment: Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in D:\wamp\www\sudip\demo\cake\libs\inflector.php on line 130.  Actauly it not found page from view.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the task bar,click WAMP Icon,move to Apache,then move to Apache modules,scroll down until you find the rewrite_module..just make sure it is clicked marked true...you are good to go